# google map CSS scroll issue when I insert header on html 5 geo location app

Tags: css, html, google-maps

You will need to use Chrome for this web app to see map.  I added a fixed header of 44px to the top of my google map which is set to 100% x 100% to take up the full screen.  Now the map is vertically scrolling what looks to be 44px too much in height at the bottom. I need the map to be 100% x 100% of the remaining screen area with no scroll.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my test page:

Comment: Map on your page is not loading.

Comment: what browser?  you may need to answer yes to geolocation question.

Comment: I denied geolocation in chrome and it worked, but not in Firefox (didn't give an error), or IE8 (gave a javascript error).  Looks to me like a css problem.

Comment: Yes, can't figure out what the CSS issue is though.  I thought the map should resize to the screen but its almost sizing first then factoring in the header.  I am lost at this point

Comment: @Rocco: I am using Chrome 10.0.648.205, but I was never prompted for geolocation. Now the page seems to be gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the map div tag but the header div, i had a br that was breaking an extra line space.